# Is there a way to check the validity of internal hyperlinks/Cross references added via a bookmark inside an active word document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-interop, office-addins

I'am trying to build an ms word add-in in which ,

I wanted to check for a particular scenario,i.e say a user inserts a bookmark and later in the document adds a cross reference to this bookmark.But he then deletes the bookmark and forgets to update his document, now upon pressing ctrl+click (to follow the link) takes me to the start of the document, instead I wanted to know if we can display a specific message to the user telling him to update his document or even  remove the cross reference by any chance .

Please let me know how I can go about this ,I know how to test for invalid links with respect to toc. But this scenario is confusing.Any help is much much appreciated.Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the following logic

```
Dim doc As Word.Document

Dim fld As Word.Field

Dim rng As Word.Range

Dim str As String



Set doc = ActiveDocument

For Each fld In doc.Fields

    If fld.Type = wdFieldRef Then

        str = fld.Code

        str = Replace(str, "REF ", "")

        str = Replace(str, "\h", "")

        str = Trim(str)

      ‘need handle the error if the bookmark has been deleted.

        Set rng = doc.Bookmarks(str).Range

    End If

Next
```

if you want to further delete the cross reference to an invalid bookmark you can use Field.Result.Delete